# The phrase "periodic boundary conditions" for a two-variable PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm currently working on trying to solve a system of PDE's of the form

$c_t=D_x(c_{xx} + c_{yy})+K_1 c + K_2 d$

$d_t= D_y(d_{xx}+d_{yy})+K_3 c + K_4 d$

that has "periodic boundary conditions" on a box $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$, where the D_i and K_i are random constants (for now). I've searched extensively for the exact definition of this term, but only really came up with descriptions for a one variable ODE. I have relatively little experience with PDEs, but I understand that the boundary conditions will affect the solution to this system, so it's a phrase that I need to resolve.

Also, as a related question, I tried to solve this system based on a one-variable example using the guess

$c = c_0 e^{\sigma t} \cos(qx) \cos(ry)$

$d = d_0 e^{\sigma t} \cos(qx) \cos(ry)$

Is this the right idea? How will it interact with the "periodic boundary conditions" requirement?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Periodic BCs to my mind mean that the value of c and/or d at the boundaries fluctuates in time i.e. $c(x,t)-> c(0,t)=A sin(\omega t)$

Comment: Hm...so how does that translate to a full set of boundary conditions? Having $c(0,t)=A\sin(\omega t)$ and $d(0,t)=B\sin(\omega t)$ isn't enough to determine the system, is it?

Comment: I'm stretching my memory of this stuff a bit, but I would say that it does determine the system. Essentially what it implies is that there is no "steady state", or rather, the steady state is the systems response to the periodic fluctuations after the transient solutions from the initial conditions have decayed

Answer (score 1):

Periodic boundary conditions means that the solution is periodic as a function of each of the spatial variables. In other words $c(0,y)=c(2 \pi,y)$, $c(x,0)=c(x,2 \pi)$, similar for $d$, and a similar periodicity for the spatial derivatives. It has nothing to do with periodicity in time, which you will probably not have in this problem.

It can also be thought of as the solution living on a domain where the ends have already been glued together (which in 2D would yield the surface of a torus).

As for picking the right guess for the form of the solution, you're not really done yet. When the $K_i$ are zero, you have a heat equation in each variable separately (just with a possibly different diffusion coefficient). I suggest you look at example 5 of this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx